# Rails with unixODBC and SQL Server 2000 and FreeBSD

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem trying to deploy a Rails application
a FreeBSD server, I am using unixODBC and FreeTDS to
access the database that sits on a server with windows server
Sqlsever 2003 and 2000.
The problem is that the application can only access the database
when using the SA user sqlserver, when I try to use another user,
the application can not access. But when I test the DSN created outside
the application I can access the database with other users,
DSN using the same application.
Does anyone have an idea what might be? Ja I even put the
I created user to access the application with all rights ..
db_owner .. and so on .. and still can not access when I try to run
application with this user.

tanks!

:) Alessandra

Answer (score 0):

I realized that if I omit the user or placing a user who does not exist, but the password being the same as in SA it connects too.